# How to add a html tag in sphinx?

Tags: python, html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In Doxygen you can add a html tag inside docstrings as follow

```
"""!    
x<sub>1</sub>,
"""
```

It will generate following
[image: defines subscript text]

the stylesheet for it

```
sub {
  vertical-align: sub;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

Is that possible to do in Sphinx? If so, how?
It don't need to be in a docstring it can be anywhere in rst file.

What I tried so far in my rst file

```
x<sub>1</sub>,
.. x<sub>1</sub>,
```

without success

I tried to escape tag

```
x/<sub>1/</sub>,
```

again without success

I'm sure I missed something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:subscript:` role](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#subscript):

```
H\ :sub:`2`\ O
```

or

```
The chemical formula for pure water is |H2O|.

.. |H2O| replace:: H\ :sub:`2`\ O
```

You could also use [`:raw:`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-directive), but heed its warnings.

Comment: Congratulations on the `python-sphinx` silver badge Mr.Piercy. Well deserved, and if anything it was overdue (given it's a relatively low-traffic tag). You have certainly given me a lot, as I'm sure many of the readers have also learned a lot from you.